# VisualStudio IntelliSense/Resharper C++ doesn't work for .mm files

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2019, resharper

I've been working on a C++ file with the extension `.mm`. VisualStudio 2019's IntelliSense wasn't working, so I installed Resharper C++, but it was still not giving me any code completion or other features. However, when I renamed the file to have the `.cpp` extension it worked. Is there no way to tell Visual Studio or Reharper C++ to treat either all `.mm` files (or just a specific file) as C++ files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Visual Studio that those `.mm` files are in fact C++.

Go to menu *Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension* and add your extension
and restart Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: Lovely! I was a hoping there'd be an easy solution, I just couldn't find it and no one else on the internets seemed to be having the same problem :P